# How to display rating in SmoothStarRating from sqlite in flutter

Tags: flutter, ratingbar

I have a starsmoothrating bar in flutter. I save the rating in my note table. How can I display the same while updating the note?

```
 Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                child: Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children:<Widget>[
                      Text("Priority",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left:20.0),
                        child: Container(
                          child: SmoothStarRating(
                            size: height=50.0,
                            allowHalfRating: false,
                            onRated: (value) {
                              this.note.prty=value;
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                      )]),
              ),
```

Comment: you can use setState and add the value you get to rating parameter of SmoothStarRating.

Comment: It worked when i want to open existing note for editing but it gives the following error when I want to open a new note   'package:smooth_star_rating/smooth_star_rating.dart': Failed assertion: line 38 pos 12: 'this.rating != null': is not true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes thanku Krish Bhanushali it worked
I just used the rating parameter.

```
SmoothStarRating(
                            size: height=50.0,
                            allowHalfRating: false,
                            rating: note.prty ?? 0,
                            onRated: (v) {
                              setState(() {
                                this.note.prty=v;

                              });
                              
                            },
                          ),
```

Comment: It worked when i want to open existing note for editing but it gives the following error when I want to open a new note 'package:smooth_star_rating/smooth_star_rating.dart': Failed assertion: line 38 pos 12: 'this.rating != null': is not true.

Comment: replace rating with rating: note.prty ?? 0

Answer (score 0):

**so use set state like i use in my below example and i give mention example below.**

```
 SmoothStarRating(
                                    allowHalfRating: false,
                                     onRated: (v) {
                                      setState(() {
                                         rating=v;
                                       });
                                       print(rating);
                                    },
                                     starCount: 5,

                                     size: 40.0,
                                     // isReadOnly:true,
                                     filledIconData: Icons.star,
                                     halfFilledIconData: Icons.star_half,
                                     color: MyColors.black,
                                     borderColor: MyColors.grey,
                                     spacing:0.0
                                 ),
```

Comment: No this is not working. I want to diplay the rating stored in database. I have the rating as 4.0 in database. so when i click on that note I want the 4 stars to be filled. And then if I change rating as 2 then database should be updated as 2